# 19.10 and android mount : no such inteface org.gtk.vfs.Mount

Tags: android

I have installed `gmtp:amd64` and `jmtpfs:amd64` and on connecting via USB and granting access from the phone get error dialog:

```
No such interface "org.gtk.vfs.Mount" on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/mount/1
```

I usually transfer files via wifi but my wifi is broken and won't be replaced for a week.

I have tried bluetooth but I have issues there I'll put to another question.

Comment: AFAIK Android USB mount comes out of the box on a desktop Ubuntu.

Comment: No solution up to now? I am seeing the same error when I connect my Android phone to a Ubuntu 20.04 system. However this seems to be a bug in the Nemo files browser which I prefer to use. Opening the phone folders with the Gnome files browser (Nautilus) works fine!

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions:

1. Install MTP Tools via the command line. There are command line instructions online you can find for that.
2. Or, Download Android File Transfer (MTP) off of Software Packages. You can't launch the program itself because it contradicts other MTP programs, but it still solved the issue for me. Beats me why. 0_o
3. And if that doesn't work, you can enable your phone to automatically connect to any USB device. This was disabled in more recent Android versions for security reasons, and though it's a good idea, I've often found that my phone will randomly disconnect from my device, so I'll have to grant permission over and over again on my cell phone screen. Very annoying. You can enable an automatic USB connection by enabling the Developer Options in Android Settings (which is different for each manufacturer and model)- then by going to USB options.

Comment: Eventually, multiple attempts, I got to a point where I opened the android transfer app and was warned about `/usr/libexec/gvfsd-mtp` blocking mtp access (not a problem with my phone, but seems to jive badly with my tablet) so I ran `kill x`, where x is the PID of that program. Then I re-opened the file transfer app, it sucked so I closed it. But then my tablet became available in file manager.
Search your running processes for things containing "mtp"/that work the same way as the app I was warned about, and halt them. then you should be good to go. thanks Ryan! I'd already tried 1 and 3.