# Unable to mount Samsung SM-A260F in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mount, android

When trying to connect my Samsung SM-A260F to two Ubuntu 20.04 desktop computers running Unity interface, selecting *Transfer files* and then *Allow access*, I get:

> No such interface "org.gtk.vfsMount" on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/-mount/1

and:

> Unable to mount SMTP device.
> SMTP tools is installed.

I have tried these solutions, except for the "force overwrite" options: [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in).
When I try to run:

```
$ sudo su -
# mv /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ~
```

I get:

```
mv: cannot stat '/var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': No such file or directory
```

I have an identical Ubuntu installation in my laptop, where I get the same error message, but then, in spite thereof, the phone does connect with no further problems.

If I connect the phone and then reboot Ubuntu on the desktops, the system usually does find the phone, but not always. It has, at times, found the connection and then lost it after a while.

I have reinstalled all the SMTP and Android packages via Synaptic Package Manager - no change.

There appears to be a problem with this specific Ubuntu installation which has been ongoing for some time, but which is somehow being bypassed by my Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Re: "*No such interface "org.gtk.vfsMount" on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/-mount/1*", looks like there's a similar question: [19.10 and android mount : no such inteface org.gtk.vfs.Mount](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204444/331791)

Comment: Thanks but I have been to that page and tried all the solutions offered there, no success.

Comment: At least in Linux Mint, the solution is to `sudo apt-get -y install mtp-tools` and then make sure you first unlock the phone by typing the phone password and only then connect the phone to the computer via USB.